# How does one edit "EditForm.aspx?" in Calendar List

Tags: calendar, edit-form

My customer would like to increase the size of the default "Description" field in EditForm.aspx? of a calendar list.  I assume this requires editing via SharePoint Designer as I cannot use InfoPath to add an overlay.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be possible, if you using the default Description field that comes with a calendar list. Reason being that this field is pulled in via an iframe. Although modifying those might be possible using some javascript, it's not recommended.

I would suggest creating an new (second) description field and hide the original one.
Than you can apply something this.

Edit your "NewForm.apsx" and add a Script Editor web-part.
[image]

Than insert some CSS to modify the field.
[image]

```
<style>
.ms-inputBox p {
    font-size: 30px !important;;
}
</style>
```

And your new text box should be looking something like this.
[image]

Hope this help.